# Google calendar embedded but looks terrible

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have embedded a google calendar but I cannot set it so that it is positioned in the center of the page and also not flooding over the top menu.

How do I go about rectifying this?

You can see what I mean by going here:http://lichfieldrooms.uk/calendar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `text-align:center;` in the `.block` part of the css for `calendar.html`.